# Like con variable en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta con `eloquent` con un dato que traigo de mi archivo `excel`, el dato que me trae es el siguiente `Lab Espectroscopía - ICP` Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta donde el nombre de mi laboratorio contenga "Lab Espectroscopía" sin contar la otra parte

```
$id = tbl_laboratorio::select('lab_id')->where('lab_nombre','like',$row['cliente'])
```

Lo pienso hacer con like pero me tomaria todo el nombre incluyendo la parte que no quiero, no se si a lo mejor con `'_',$row['cliente']` pueda conseguirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es omitir la otra parte te recomiendo utilizar el simbolo '%' seguido de tu variable de cliente por ejemplo:

```
$id = tbl_laboratorio::select('lab_id')->where('lab_nombre','like',$row['cliente'].'%')
```

Comment: El punto que pones para que es?

Comment: El like que utilizas en tu pregunta está buscando una coincidencia exacta con la palabra Lab Espectroscopía pero como dices que el dato contiene al final - ICP entonces no la va a encontrar, por el valor '%' después de la palabra a buscar te ayuda a omitir lo que esta demas. "El punto es para concatenar los strings"

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias funciona :D, por ejemplo yo use algo como esto:

```
$productos=DB::table('productos')->orwhere('nombre','=',$nombre)->orwhere('nombre','like','%'.$nombre)->orWhere('nombre','like','%'.$nombre.'%')->orWhere('nombre','like',$nombre.'%')->paginate(8);
```

Comment: $cantidad=DB::table('productos')->orwhere('nombre','=',$nombre)->orwhere('nombre','like','%'.$nombre)->orWhere('nombre','like','%'.$nombre.'%')->orWhere('nombre','like',$nombre.'%')->where('nombre','=',$nombre)->count();

Comment: La solución esta en la respuesta o en el comentario?

Comment: en ambos, es que uso una variable $cantidad para que la paginación sea variable dependiendo de los elementos que encuentre que contengan los caracteres que tengo en esa variable($nombre), el orden correcto es primero el comentario, luego la respuesta, disculpa el desorden!!

Comment: La solución solo va en la respuesta, por favor edita y agrega en la misma todo lo que consideres necesario